# Mocking of services ,directives in ng controller

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

In Jasmine unit test i am writing I am facing issue related to mocking of services and directive in controller.

I have mocked by $injecting.

```
var someModelObj
beforeEach(inject(function (_someModel_) {
        someModelObj= _someModel_;
    }));
```

TypeError: someModelObj.prepareGetSomeItemsRequestParams is not a function

Please let me know how to solve these type of error.

Comment: You only injected model. Maybe your model doesn't have this method?

Comment: thank you ,this is the private services